# Find a polynomial $f(Z)$ of degree less than 2 such that $e^{tA}=f(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&-2\\2&-2\end{pmatrix}$. As the question says I need a polynomial $f(Z)$ of degree less than 2 such that $e^{tA}=f(A)$.

Should my polynomial just be the first 2 terms of the exponential summation? i.e. $I_2+tA$ or does it mean something else?

I've already worked out that $e^{tA}=-\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}e^{-t}-4e^{2t}&-2e^{-t}+2e^{2t}\\2e^{-t}-2e^{2t}&-4e^{-t}+e^{2t}\end{pmatrix}$

I just don't know what polynomial it wants.

Edit: Diagonalising $A$ gives $\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ doesn't it? But what do I do with that to get the polynomial it asks for?

Edit 2: So I've worked out $c_0(t)=\frac{1}{3}(e^{2t}+2e^{-t})$ and $c_1(t)=\frac{1}{3}(e^{2t}-e^{-t})$. Are they like the coefficients for the polynomial? Or is there something else?

Comment: Hint: diagonalize $A$. $e^{tA} = \sum \frac{t^kA^k}{k!}$

Comment: So you know that for some invertible matrix $P$ you have
$$B=PAP^{-1}=\pmatrix{-1&0\cr0&2\cr}.$$ Can you find scalars $c_0(t),c_1(t)$ (they will necessarily depend on $t$) such that
$$e^{tB}=\pmatrix{e^{-t}&0\cr 0&e^{2t}\cr}=c_0(t)I+c_1(t)B?$$
What happens when you conjugate this by $P^{-1}$? IOW - what Mustafa said!

Comment: For Edit 2: Yes, as follows from previous comment:
$$e^{tA}=c_0(t)\,I+c_1(t)\,A\,.=p(A)$$
for $p(X)=c_0(t)+c_1(t)X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

You already have $\exp(tA)$ so you only need to write it as $\alpha(t)\cdot A + \beta(t)$
and find $\alpha(t)$, $\beta(t)$ ( you get an overdetermined system that still has a unique solution)

\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha (t) &=& -1/3\, e^{-t} + 1/3 \,e^{2t}\\
\beta(t) &=&\ \ \ \ \   2/3\, e^{-t}  + 1/3\, e^{2t}
\end{eqnarray}

${\bf Added:}$

Based on @loup blanc: answer

In general, if $A$ satisfies $P(A)=0$, a polynomial equation of degree $n$, then  for every  analytic function $f$ defined around the roots of $P$ we have $f(A)=R(A)$  where $R$  is the polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ 
that interpolates the function $f$ on the roots of $P$. (Lagrange or Hermite iterpolation). This is in fact functional calculus on the algebra generated by $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is the polynomial of degree $1$, s.t. $f(-1)=e^{-t},f(2)=e^{2t}$.

Comment: This is the educated approach. Great! +1

Comment: Thanks, I see: if $A$ satisfies an equation $P(A) = 0$ of $\deg n$ and you want $f(A)$ then find a polynomial of $\deg \le n-1$ that interpolates $f$ on the roots of $P$  (Lagrange or Hermite).